# Python - textual analysis - search for phrases instead of simple words (tokens)

Tags: python, regex

I have a document in python which I read in the following way:

```
tokens = re.findall('\w+', doc)  # Note that \w+ splits hyphenated words
for token in tokens:
```

The problem with this is that I can search for simple words (e.g. "bananas", but not for phrases, e.g. "yellow bananas"). How should I change my code in order to be able to search for phrases on top of simple words?

Seems like I somehow need to read the whole file as a string instead of tokenizing it word by word?

Comment: Do you have any rules that determines which is phrases?

Comment: By the way, you should use `r'\w+'` or `'\\w+'` instead of `'\w+'`. You IDE would tell you about this.

Comment: You you want general phrase detection, you cannot achieve that with regex. You need language models(dependency parsing, POS Tagger, ...).

Comment: Can you give me some code that reads the whole file instead of tokenizing it by word?

Comment: Why do you tokenize then? I guess you want to just get the words and then join them with space, since it looks as if your "phrases" are single space separated words, right? Use `clean_text = " ".join(re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)*', text))` and then you may simply use `.find()`, Reading a file into a single string is a well-known thing, like `with open(path, 'r') as fr: text = fr.read()`.

Comment: You are right @WiktorStribiżew I was not familiar with this regex etc. If you post it below I will accept your answer since it seems to be what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to get the words and then join them with space, since your "phrases"  seem to be single space separated words. Use

```
text = ''
with open(path, 'r') as fr:
    text = fr.read()
clean_text = " ".join(re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)*', text))
```

Then, you may simply use `.find()`.

The `\w+(?:-\w+)*` pattern extracts both hyphenated and non-hyphenated words:

- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits, `_`s
- `(?:-\w+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `-` - a hyphen
- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits, `_`s.

Comment: And then how do I search for phrases? Can you give an example in your post?

Comment: @adrCoder I am not sure what you want to do in the end, [here](https://ideone.com/2KvbOO) is some very basic code. Please edit the question once you know what exactly you need.

Comment: Let's say I want to count how many times the phrase "yellow bananas" or "systemic risk factors" are contained in the text. How do I do that? I saw now that the link you pasted does that - thanks!